# Power of paired t-test: R vs. SAS

Tags: r, t-test, sas, statistical-power

If we are trying to find the power of a paired t-test, SAS offers this template (among others) in `PROC POWER`:

```
   proc power;
      pairedmeans test=diff
         meandiff = 7
         corr = 0.4
         stddev = 12
         npairs = 50
         power = .;
   run;
```

R, on the other hand, has this:

```
pwr.t.test(n = NULL, d = NULL, sig.level = 0.05, power = NULL, 
    type = c("two.sample", "one.sample", "paired"),
    alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"))
```

where there is no way to specify the correlation. But the correlation makes a huge difference to the results. d (the effect size) is Cohen's d (difference in the means divided by pooled standard deviation).

Is this an error in the R program (that seems very unlikely) or have I missed something (far more likely) and, if I have missed something, what is it I have missed?

Comment: I presume you're using the function from the R package `pwr`. See the second example in the help of `pwr.t.test` (that `sqrt(1-0.6)` in the calculation of `d` is where the correlation comes in; the correlation in that example was 0.6). Compare against Cohen (1988) *Statistical power analysis for the behavioral sciences* (2ed.) as indicated in the help.

Comment: Ah.  Now I see. Thanks. I still think the SAS method is easier to use, but at least I realize that R is also correct (which I was pretty sure of, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the pooled standard deviation accounts for the covariance between time point 1 and time point 2.  R requires Cohen's d, which makes use of the difference between the two means and the pooled standard deviation. R, perhaps, directly makes use of Cohen's d to calculate power. In SAS you can specify the correlation separately, but if you change your correlation, your SD will also change.

Comment: I am sure you are right, but I don't quite see it. The pooled sd includes the sample sizes of each sample and the variance of each sample. Where does the correlation come in?

Comment: If X1 and X2 are not independent, then Var(X1-X2) = Var(X1) + Var(X2) - 2 COV(X1, X2). COV(X1, X2) = SD(X1) SD(X2) COR(X1, X2). That's my understanding of it. I could be wrong.